# Zombie object, requireGestureRecognizerToFail, why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nszombie

I have two VC's, both host a uicollectionviews, in one of them ( Call it VC1) I add a

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr
= [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
   initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
lpgr.minimumPressDuration = .8; //seconds
lpgr.delegate = self;
[self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
// Make the default gesture recognizer wait until the custom one fails.
for (UIGestureRecognizer* aRecognizer in [self.collectionView gestureRecognizers]) {
    if ([aRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]])
        [aRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:lpgr];
}
```

Now through the app life cycle the user can switch from this VC1 to another VC2. 
In that instance I get a crash, if I load the app and go to VC2 and never hit VC1 this never happens. So after losing valuable time figuring out how to debug this I ran zombies in instruments and discovered that the line

```
  [aRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:lpgr];
```

Was the problem, although this line is in the

```
viewdidload
```

of VC1, if I move from VC1 to VC2 this gets called !!

I disabled that segment and my code works fine, I just don't know why would this happen!!

Answer (score 0):

You should not create a dependency relationship to object itself.
As you already add a gesture recognizer **lpgr** to collectionview, in your for-loop, bad dependency relationship in **lpgr** itself can be created.

Rewrite it like this.

```
// Make the default gesture recognizer wait until the custom one fails.
for (UIGestureRecognizer* aRecognizer in [self.collectionView gestureRecognizers]) {
    if ([aRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]])
        [aRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:lpgr];
}

[self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
```